# Issues while comparing float32 objects in dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe data which is like this:

```
>>> data.head(10)
              stock   pop    ma  order
Date
2016-01-04  325.316  82.0   NaN     -1
2016-01-11  320.036  83.0   NaN     -1
2016-01-18  299.169  79.0  82.5     -1
2016-01-25  296.579  84.0  81.0     -1
2016-02-01  295.334  82.0  81.5     -1
2016-02-08  309.777  81.0  83.0     -1
2016-02-15  317.397  75.0  81.5     -1
2016-02-22  328.005  80.0  78.0     -1
2016-02-29  315.504  81.0  77.5     -1
2016-03-07  328.802  81.0  80.5     -1
```

So I wanted to compare data.po with data.ma.If po is greater than ma then order would be -1 and if po is less than ma then it is 1. I wrote the following code for it.

```
data['order'][data.pop > data.ma] = -1
data['order'][data.pop < data.ma] = 1
```

After I run ma greater than po there is no change in order values. And as seen in the table when I run pop greater than ma code everything turns -1. Intially, I thought it must be error of datatypes so I made sure both were same and converted them both to float32. It did not run even after that.

```
>>> data.dtypes
stock    float64
pop      float32
ma       float32
order      int64
dtype: object
```

Any suggestions what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are running into chained indexing - running this interactively you'll see a warning, see also the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Second, `pop` is a DataFrame method, so `data.pop` is actually returning that method, not the column name.  The safe way to access that column is `data['pop']`.

So you could write it like this:

```
data.loc[data['pop'] > data['ma'], 'order'] = -1

data.loc[data['pop'] < data['ma'], 'order'] = 1

data

              stock   pop    ma  order
Date                                  
2016-01-04  325.316  82.0   NaN     -1
2016-01-11  320.036  83.0   NaN     -1
2016-01-18  299.169  79.0  82.5      1
2016-01-25  296.579  84.0  81.0     -1
2016-02-01  295.334  82.0  81.5     -1
2016-02-08  309.777  81.0  83.0      1
2016-02-15  317.397  75.0  81.5      1
2016-02-22  328.005  80.0  78.0     -1
2016-02-29  315.504  81.0  77.5     -1
2016-03-07  328.802  81.0  80.5     -1
```

Comment: I see so basically the code I wrote was comparing methods and hence the output was same everytime. Understood and thanks a lot!